# Static Homepage Not Working on Wordpress Localhost

Tags: wordpress

Recently copied over a WordPress live site over to localhost and I am having trouble getting my homepage to display correctly.

On my live site and local version, the static page is set to "Home" (home.php) in the Reading setting.

On my live site, using Theme Header Check, it states the

> Template relative path: themes/custom-theme/home.php

which is correct.

On my local version, it states

> Template relative path: themes/custom-theme/page.php

Which displays nothing because we do not use page.php on live site.

Everything else is working on my local copy just fine. The homepage loads fine, header, footer, backend, etc. The only issue is the homepage is directing to page.php instead of home.php for the content of the homepage.

Anyone have a solution for this?  I am unable to make edits to homepage without getting this resolved.

Comment: may be you have page-home.php template in live site and in your local its missing have you checked that ?

Comment: home.php is in local.  I made sure to copy all files from my FTP so I am sure I did not miss anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working after some fiddling around.

Apparently when I transferred over to local the template for 'Home' was reset to default-template.

So I simply went to my pages, clicked edit Home (front page), and set my page template in the page attributes to the proper template file.